Частичная быстрая перерисовка некоторых элементов QwtPlot
Существует ли альтернатива методу replot() класса QwtPlot? Необходимо отрисовывать некоторые элементы находящиеся на QwtPlot (к примеру QwtPlotMarker, который перемещаю на 1 пиксель при нажатии на QPushButton), перерисовка всего пространства QwtPlot методом replot() занимает много ресурсов, из-за чего даже один маркер двигается с небольшими рывками.
Склоняюсь к тому, что нужно смотреть в сторону частичной перерисовки, обнаружил класс QwtWidgetOverlay, но не очень понимаю, как его задействовать (нужно переопределить методы drawOverlay() и maskHint(), а что дальше - непонятно)
